# ExtJS call directFn, failed

Tags: extjs

In the ExtJS 3, I want to invoke a method, like below. Looks like method in server side is not invoked. I can't use 'directFn' this way ? how to fix it ?

The server side is C#.

Thanks

```
function showDetail(recordId) {    
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        directFn: Report.showDetail,
        success: received,
        failure: function () { alert('failure'); },
        params: { recordId: recordId }
    });
}

function received(response) {
    var x = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
    alert(x);
}
```

Comment: Where are you seeing a directFn parameter to the request method?

Answer (score 1):

Uh, yeah, you can't just create a parameter and expect it to mean something to Ext. You'll need to call a url and pass directFn as part of the url or as a parameter, depending on how your server-side stuff is set up.